# Choose countries in html/js with translate

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code for Google Translate. Countries are : United States, Canada, Spain and France. I need help how to know which country(not language) is selected to use that value for further coding. Also I need to examine that value to all my website pages.

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="translation-links">
<li style="text-align: center; padding: 12px; float: left;"><a href="#" 
class="english 1" data-lang="English"><img class="img-responsive" 
style="text-align: justify;" title="United States" src="/imagepull.php? 
img_id=852232" alt="United States" /></a></li>
<li style="text-align: center; padding: 12px; float: left;"><a href="#" 
class="english 2" data-lang="English"><img class="img-responsive" 
style="text-align: justify;" title="Canada" src="/imagepull.php? 
img_id=852233" alt="Canada" /></a></li>
<li style="text-align: center; padding: 12px; float: left;"><a href="#" 
class="french" data-lang="French"><img class="img-responsive" style="text- 
align: justify;" title="France" src="/imagepull.php?img_id=852237" 
alt="France" /></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
   new google.translate.TranslateElement({
   pageLanguage: 'en',
   includedLanguages: 'en,fr,de,it,es',
   layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, 
   autoDisplay: false, multilanguagePage: 
   true, gaTrack: true, gaId: 'UA-21881206-1'
   }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.translation-links a').click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).data('lang');
    var $frame = $('.goog-te-menu-frame:first');
    if (!$frame.size()) {
       alert("Error: Could not find Google translate frame.");
       return false;
    }
$frame.contents().find('.goog-te-menu2-item 
    span.text:contains('+lang+')').get(0).click();
    return false;
 });
</script>
<script src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? 
cb=googleTranslateElementInit" 
type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: Please add som code and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @Cikapera What is your problem? and how are you trying to approach? maybe post some code and read the FAQ from Stack Overflow to get some useful help

Comment: Sorry for this. I have code now.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use **localStorage** to pass the language variable between pages.

here are the local storage docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

The way i see it goes is like this:

```
// get language variable by prompt or dropdown list.
// for example: **var lang = prompt('please type your language.','English');**
```

then:

```
localStorage.setItem('language',lang);
```

or

```
localStorage.language = lang;
```

and get the value in other page by using:

```
var lang = localStorage.getItem('language');
```

or

```
var lang = localStorage.language;
```

there is also information about web storage here:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

keep in mind that you should check if the browser supports web storage like this:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
} else {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

Comment: I need country name,  not language.

Comment: So you can create a mapping (js object) that will map between the country name and the languages that you support.
The main idea of my answer is the use of local storage to pass variables between multiple pages, and with local storage you may won't need to ask the same user (from the same browser) for the country in his next visit in your website (unless he cleared the local storage)